# Is there a way to delete all files related to Ckeditor gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ckeditor

I am using Rails 4.2 and Git, recently I have installed the [Ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) but after a while I decided to discard all the changes (include deleting all files added by ckeditor gem)

the first thing I did is committing the changes :

```
git add .
git commit -am "added ckeditor"
```

then I run the following to delete this commit with :

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

and it seem that it works fine... but the only problem I have now is :

Every time I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

there is a table **ckeditor_assets** which is automatically added to my schema ! I don't know what to do about that and also I am not sure if there is a hidden file somewhere which is responsible of that and how to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the following steps to resolve your problem:

1. Remove CKEditor migrations. Check `db/migrations` directory.
2. Rollback applied CKEditor migrations use `rake db:rollback` or drop, create and migrate database.

Comment: there are no migrations files of CKEditor under db/migrations  !!

Comment: So, check them in `db/schema.rb`

Comment: in the db/schema.rb I can see the table related to the CKEditor but I don't know what to do about it ?

Comment: Drop, create and migrate tasks should rebuild your `schema.rb`: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: or just remove `db/schema.rb` and run `rake db:migrate`. It should rebuild `schema.rb` file from your migrations.

Comment: humm it works thank you so much :) but I still don't understand why before when i run db:migrate it create this table even if the migration file doesn't exist under db/migration.

Comment: removing db/schema.rb doesn't work for me, what works is rake db:drop then rake db:create

Comment: [Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark) is answer to your question.